# Word 2007 OLE Locks File and Won't Close

Tags: windows-7, ms-word, locking, 64-bit, ole

My application recognises RTF on the clipboard and 'Paste' saves that RTF to a temporary RTF file. I then use `COleClientItem::CreateFromFile` to embed the data as an OLE RTF document (rendered by Word). I then try to remove the temporary file.

On WinXP / Office 2003 this was all fine. Since I moved to Win7(x64)/Office 2007, Word hangs around, locking the temp RTF file. `COleClientItem::Close` doesn't do anything. Is there anyway I can prevent Word from locking the file so I can delete it? (I don't mind Word hanging around that much, if I could tidy up properly).